# RapidJson Memory Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, rapidjson

I'm in the process of developing a Swagger API document merger, **in C++ using the RapidJson Library**, that takes multiple Swagger JSON document files and combines them into a single JSON document. I'm using RapidJson to load, dynamically modify JSON and serialise it to file. In the process of doing so I've encountered a very strange error:

The process seems to work up until a certain point (**usually up to circa 25kb of memory utilisation**) and then begins to crash with **Segmentation Fault** being reported as the cause. Here's some snippets of the relevant parts of the code:

So firstly I generate a base Swagger document (which all sub documents will eventually be append to) and populate the top level details:

```
string base_api_json=R"json({
"swagger": "2.0",
"info": {
    "description": "a desc",
    "version": "1.0-SNAPSHOT",
    "title": "a title"
},
"host": "host:port",
"basePath": "/",
"tags": [],
"schemes": [],
"paths": {},
"definitions": {}
})json";

//parse the base document template to a Document instance...
Document* baseApiDoc = parseJsonStrToObject(base_api_json.c_str()); 

//dynamically populate the top-level document attributes
Value& swaggerVersion = (*baseApiDoc)["swagger"];
Value& info = (*baseApiDoc)["info"];
Value& title = info["title"];
Value& description = info["description"];
Value& version = info["version"];
Value& host = (*baseApiDoc)["host"];
Value& basePath = (*baseApiDoc)["basePath"];

swaggerVersion.SetString(configSwaggerVersion.GetString(),configSwaggerVersion.GetStringLength());

title.SetString(configTitle.GetString(),configTitle.GetStringLength());

description.SetString(configDescription.GetString(),configDescription.GetStringLength());

version.SetString(configApiVersion.GetString(),configApiVersion.GetStringLength());

host.SetString(configHost.GetString(),configHost.GetStringLength());

basePath.SetString(configBasePath.GetString(),configBasePath.GetStringLength());

//finally write the document out to file as a JSON string..
ofstream ofs("output.json");
OStreamWrapper osw(ofs);
Writer<OStreamWrapper> writer(osw);
baseApiDoc->Accept(writer);
```

This all works as expected and I'm able to successfully write the contents out to file as valid JSON. The problem occurs when I attempt to dynamically populate the **paths** node in the document via the RapidJson **AddMember** function. I'm attempting to append standard Swagger Path definitions to the document that take the following form:

```
"/api/v1/partners": {
"get": {
"tags": [
  "partner-resource"
],
"summary": "List Partners",
"description": "Lists all currently registered partners.",
"operationId": "listPartnersUsingGET",
"produces": [
  "*/*"
],
"parameters": [
  {
    "name": "includeDeleted",
    "in": "query",
    "description": "A boolean value that indicates whether or not (soft) deleted items should be included in the returned results, they are not by default. ",
    "required": false,
    "type": "boolean"
  },
  {
    "name": "includeInactive",
    "in": "query",
    "description": "A boolean value that indicates whether or not inactive items should be included in the returned results, they are not by default.",
    "required": false,
    "type": "boolean"
  },
  {
    "name": "X-AUTH-KEY",
    "in": "header",
    "description": "The users Session Id.  ",
    "required": false,
    "type": "string",
    "x-example": "65646467-e654-4544-ab89-ab4665465d5dde56"
  }
],
"responses": {
  "200": {
    "description": "OK",
    "schema": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/ServiceResponse«Partner»"
    }
  },
  "401": {
    "description": "Unauthorized"
  },
  "403": {
    "description": "Forbidden"
  },
  "404": {
    "description": "Not Found"
  }
}
}
}
```

These paths are loaded in from another document (this process has been omitted for brevity) and then appended to the **paths** node of the document we generated above. The resulting path instance is appended as follows:

```
//firstly obtain reference to the paths node in the baseAPIdoc...
Value& baseApiDocPaths = (*baseApiDoc["paths"];

//append path to base doc
baseApiDocPaths.AddMember("/api/v1/partners",curSubApiPathValue,rjAllocator);
```

As mentioned previously this works perfectly until around 25kb of memory utilisation and then fails with a Segmentation Fault during the process of serialisation, the line that fails (that worked previously) is:

```
baseApiDoc->Accept(writer);
```

In attempting to solve the problem, I followed the advice in the following technical [article](https://techoverflow.net/2020/01/13/how-to-fix-rapidjson-segmentation-faults-when-building-nested-documents/) which essentially recommend using a single: `MemoryPoolAllocator<>` for all modifications to the Document, to no avail. Finally I allocated more initial memory to the RapidJson Allocator instance (which defaults to 1024) before attempting to process the JSON document:

```
MemoryPoolAllocator<> rjAllocator;   
rjAllocator.Malloc(65000);
```

This also has no effect. From what I can gather, it would seem that the `document.Accept()` and `AddMember` functions use their own **internal** MemoryPoolAllocators (and the specification of a global MemoryPoolAllocator seems to take no effect.) **and when these MemoryPoolAllocators internally fail to dynamically allocate a sufficient amount of memory, a Segmentation Fault results** Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does no one have a clue what the issue may be? A cursory search seems to suggest that it's a common problem. Not sure if its worth reaching out to the developers directly. In the event I do, I'll be sure to update this question with any relevant findings.

Comment: Ok so, after a significant debug session,I’ve managed to solve the problem. The solution is a little obscure as it dictates use of the RapidJson library in a way that is subtilely but substantial different to the examples outlined in the official documentation published by the library's developers. I'm unable to answer my own question for the next two days;, I will post the solution as soon as I'm able to, in the hope that it will aid others that subsequently encounter this, seemingly, fairly common problem.

Comment: Can you please share your solution?